# Private variables inside DelegatingHandler mixing values from other requests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We have a DelegatingHandler implemented that has some private variables and 2 of them are getting values from different parallel requests than their own even though they are not static variables

```
public sealed class XYZProxyHandler:DelegatingHandler
{
    private string _var1;
    private string _var2;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = request.Headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault().Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "access_token").Value;
        _var1 = GetVar1(token);
        _var2 = GetVar2(token);
```

Tried to make it as simple of code while including an important piece of code.
In the above sample code, ideally _var1 and _var2 should get the values of its own request but for whatever reason, they sometimes get other request's values.
I have instances of _var1 getting the value of another request but _var2 gets the value of its own request and vice-versa.

I have run into this type of behaviour before when a static variable is shared across requests but these are not static variables and hence I am not sure how it can happen or if it is something to do with DelegatingHandler implementation.

I have tried to test it but did not reproduce it and am working on the same with more variations of test data and this happens 50 times in a month maybe so not very often.

I am not sure if I am being tunnel visioned and not seeing something obvious or glaring.

Comment: This means that multiple requests are sharing instances of this non-thread-safe class. Registering it as a scoped dependency should fix it. Or, if the real code closely resembles this, move the variable declarations into the method instead of using fields. That way each time the method is executed it creates new variables which aren't shared with other executions.

Comment: what is the reason to store these values in the instance - you want to reuse them or smth else?

Comment: @ScottHannen thats what i presumed has to be the case but i thought each http request will instantiate its own XYZProxyhandler object. Is that not the case here? Any place link that explain this?

Comment: The information about when these are instantiated isn't shown. But the behavior you're describing - this happens once in a while, inconsistently - is a clear indication of a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)-class is simultaneously consumed by all requests that the app receives so this behavior is predictable.

I would get rid of any local variables and pass the required values directly:

```
public sealed class XYZProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   // If needed some thread-safe service, repo, etc can be passed in the constructor.
    /*
    private readonly ISmth _smth;

    public XYZProxyHandler(ISmth smth) 
    {
        _smth = smth;
    }
    */

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = request.Headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault().Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "access_token").Value;
        var _var1 = GetVar1(token);
        var _var2 = GetVar2(token);

        SomeMethod(_var1, _var2);

        // ..
    }

    private void SomeMethod(string one, string two) {


    }
}
```

Comment: I assumed that since this is not a static class, each request will get its own handler object but seems like that is not the case and all requests share the same object.
Can you share some link where this case is explained as it seems i am missing something on main documentation?

Comment: Just look at the [handler registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers#adding-a-handler-to-the-pipeline) - it is instantiated just once and *WebApiConfig.Register*-method is called when *HttpApplication* initialized.

Comment: i had the same thought and just wanted to confirm. I just tested by putting thread sleep between two variable and was able to reproduce it. So essentially all requests share the same handler object.